# Can you use {} (format) within sql_raw query for assigning a date?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I am wishing to assign a date in an sql query using a variable, rather than manually entering. I have tried the following below but I get a `IndexError: tuple index out of range`

```
us_ids #list of ids
placeholders_id = ','.join('%s' for i in range(len(us_ids)))  # '?,?'

start = '2000/01/01'
end = '2020/12/31'
```

**Query desired**

```
sql_query = '''
SELECT *
FROM a.b
WHERE date between ({}) and ({})
and relevance >= 90
and id IN ({})'''.format(start, end, placeholders_id)

sql_call = conn.raw_sql(sql_query, params=(us_ids))
```

**When I manually set the date, as below, it works.**

```
sql_query = '''
SELECT *
FROM a.b
WHERE date between '2000/01/01' and '2020/12/01'
and relevance >= 90
and id IN ({})'''.format(start, end, placeholders_id)

sql_call = conn.raw_sql(sql_query, params=(us_ids))
```

Any help would be awesome!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can you use {} (format) within sql_raw query for assigning a date?

Please do not do it. Passing values to queries using string formatting is error prone, as you have demonstrated, and can result in SQL injection. Use the exact same method for passing the date literals as you have done with the IN value list:

```
sql_query = '''
SELECT *
FROM a.b
WHERE date between %s and %s
and relevance >= 90
and id IN ({})'''.format(placeholders_id)

sql_call = conn.raw_sql(sql_query, params=(start, end, *us_ids))
```